Allow comma (in addition to dot) in decimals for form validations in CodeIgniter 4
I have a pretty simple task and I don't know how to adjust my code to an extend, which solves my problem:
I have a pretty simple form with an input-field like this:
<input type="text" name="weight">

In my controller, after calling the respective function, I end up in my validation-part. Have a look here:
public function store()
{
    helper(['form']);
    $data = [];
    
    $rules = [
        'currentWeight' => [
            'label'  => 'weight',
            'rules'  => 'required|numeric',
            'errors' => [
                'required'   => 'The {field} is required.',
                'numeric'    => '{field} needs to be numeric (e.g. 88.2)'
            ]
        ],
    ];
    
    
    if($this->validate($rules)) {           
        $data = [
            'weight'  => $this->request->getVar('currentWeight'),
        ];
        
        $data["success"] = "New Entry point set";
        echo view('useradmin/insert_weight', $data);
        
    } else {
        $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        echo view('useradmin/insert_weight', $data);
    }
}

So, as you can see, this is super simple. However, the decimal-rule from CI4 only allows . in a decimal-number. So basically, 88.2 is allowed, while 88,2 isn't. I followed a tutorial on how to use the validator, but everywhere else, it seems like they are doing it different.
My initial thought was, that I could simply str_replace the comma with a dot and let it be checked afterwards. However, it seems like I can't hook into the $this->validate function with custom rules or even adjusted variables.
I know that I could potentially add a new rule, which takes care of the , in such numbers, but I thought that there would be a smarter, more efficient way.
I also tried using some sort of callbacks, which I wasn't able to address properly.
From what I have gathered, it seems like there is also an option to use a validation-helper or similar functions like validateData(), but I'm kinda stuck here.
I also wasn't able to find some kind of locales, which might have solved the problem with the decimal-point. Could you point me in the right direction? I'm using CI 4.5.5
(I found similar questions like this here: Codeigniter form validation allow numeric type to include comma - but this is heavily outdated)

With CI4 you can adjust things if you need (just remember to reapply on future updates). The code in question is under System > Validation > FormatRules and you'll see the following as part of the numeric function.
// @see https://regex101.com/r/bb9wtr/2
return (bool) preg_match('/\A[\-+]?\d*\.?\d+\z/', $str);

You should adjust so that the preg match is \A[\-+]?\d*[\.\,]?\d+\z instead and this will work (according to the regex101 page).
